# NodeJS fs module does not work in Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, fs

I'm using this module for my app on Openshift but when it needs to execute the function that checks if a file exists in the Data folder appers an error:

```
DEBUG: /var/lib/openshift/02A50df2XXYD46273d00FFG8/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:164
        fs.exists('$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/data/' + user_ip, function(exis
           ^

DEBUG: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exists'
```

I have the require fs in the server code and it's in dependencies at package.json

EDIT: Solved

Using `require('path')` and `path.exists()` it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.exists()` has been deprecated. Instead use path.exists().
For more information on path see node core [path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module.

Comment: I tried using path.exists but when the function is executed it returns the next error: path.exists('$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/data/' + user_ip, function(exists)

DEBUG: ReferenceError: path is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Advice:
According to the API Docs http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons. There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.

In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there.

As for your issue:
Are you able to make other fs calls?

Comment: Then If I was you I would stick to using fs.open since it seems to be a better option.